# urlllib still reads over proxy when remote proxy is turned off

Tags: python, proxy, urllib, python-3.4

In a small test project, I'm trying to test a remote proxy server. We have a client that runs on the local machine that talks to the proxy server. I've setup my python code to talk over the client like so:

```
proxy_handler = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://localhost:' + self.proxy_port})
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_handler)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
```

And then I have code that opens the url and reads N bytes at a time:

```
try:
    video_stream = urllib.request.urlopen(self.url, timeout=10)

    while something_is_true:
        data = video_stream.read(bucket_size)

except URLError:
    # handle errors
except Exception:
    # handle errors
```

The problem I'm having is that I can start the test and have it run for several minutes. During that time, I can turn off the remote proxy and the code continues to read from the `video_stream` connection. No exceptions are thrown.

If I run the code with the remote proxy off from the start, it fails on `urlopen()`, which I'd expect. But I'd also expect the `read()` to fail if I stop the remote proxy during the run.